# How to solve "lcb_server_purge_implicit_responses: Assertion `nr == sizeof(req)' failed"?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, couchbase

I'm having a problem communicating an application with a CouchBase DB.

Here's my configuration:

I'm using ZendFramework 1 on top of PHP 5.3 and Apache 2.2.22. My application is backed by a CouchBase 2.0.0 database.

There are a few scripts which make some queries to the db using pre-defined views. The problem is, sometimes (I couldn't really pinpoint the scenario yet), the script would get interrupted (It doesn't throw any exception, it simply stops working). The script is run through an HTTP Request, so I picked this up from the webserver's error_log:

```
httpd: src/server.c:791: lcb_server_purge_implicit_responses: Assertion `nr == sizeof(req)' failed.
[Wed Jan 15 13:12:34 2014] [notice] child pid 16599 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

I've been googling around but didn't find anything useful (yet :). I basically have the following questions:

1. Does anybody know what conditions might trigger this error?
2. Would it be better to code this script as a CLI task (Thus bypassing Apache altogether)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the php couchbase sdk?

Comment: I checked with infrastrcture and yes, I am

Comment: What version of `libcouchbase` and the Couchbase PHP SDK are your clients using?

Answer (score 2):

It looks very similar to this defect: http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/CCBC-135.
If you can reliably reproduce please update the defect with the steps and also if you can, upload the core dump. That would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in the latest release version (2.2.0). The version you're using must be older because the 2.2.0 doesn't even have a line 791:

https://github.com/couchbase/libcouchbase/blob/2.2.0/src/server.c